# Dynamic pivot in SQL server not grouping correctly

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot-table

I'm trying to build a dynamic pivot that essentially shows subscription amounts by customer by month. The dynamic part of the pivot is working correctly, but the resulting pivot has multiple non-identical lines per customer ID and I'm not sure why. Fair warning, I'm very new to this whole SQL thing so my code may be a complete mess and for that I'm  sorry

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
        + QUOTENAME([Month])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 99.99 PERCENT [Month] FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data] ORDER BY [Month]) AS [Month]
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    N'SELECT [Customer ID], ' + @ColumnName + '
    INTO [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[Pivot_Results] FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data]
    PIVOT(SUM([Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data].[Subscription Amount]) 
            FOR [Month] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

@DynamicPivotQuery returns

```
SELECT [Customer ID], [Jan  1 2013 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2013 12:00AM],[Mar  1 2013 12:00AM],[Apr  1 2013 12:00AM],[May  1 2013 12:00AM],[Jun  1 2013 12:00AM],[Jul  1 2013 12:00AM],[Aug  1 2013 12:00AM],[Sep  1 2013 12:00AM],[Oct  1 2013 12:00AM],[Nov  1 2013 12:00AM],[Dec  1 2013 12:00AM],[Jan  1 2014 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2014 12:00AM],[Mar  1 2014 12:00AM],[Apr  1 2014 12:00AM],[May  1 2014 12:00AM],[Jun  1 2014 12:00AM],[Jul  1 2014 12:00AM],[Aug  1 2014 12:00AM],[Sep  1 2014 12:00AM],[Oct  1 2014 12:00AM],[Nov  1 2014 12:00AM],[Dec  1 2014 12:00AM],[Jan  1 2015 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2015 12:00AM],[Mar  1 2015 12:00AM],[Apr  1 2015 12:00AM],[May  1 2015 12:00AM],[Jun  1 2015 12:00AM],[Jul  1 2015 12:00AM],[Aug  1 2015 12:00AM],[Sep  1 2015 12:00AM],[Oct  1 2015 12:00AM],[Nov  1 2015 12:00AM],[Dec  1 2015 12:00AM],[Jan  1 2016 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2016 12:00AM]
    INTO [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[Pivot_Results] FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data]
    PIVOT(SUM([Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data].[Subscription Amount]) 
            FOR [Month] IN ([Jan  1 2013 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2013 12:00AM],[Mar  1 2013 12:00AM],[Apr  1 2013 12:00AM],[May  1 2013 12:00AM],[Jun  1 2013 12:00AM],[Jul  1 2013 12:00AM],[Aug  1 2013 12:00AM],[Sep  1 2013 12:00AM],[Oct  1 2013 12:00AM],[Nov  1 2013 12:00AM],[Dec  1 2013 12:00AM],[Jan  1 2014 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2014 12:00AM],[Mar  1 2014 12:00AM],[Apr  1 2014 12:00AM],[May  1 2014 12:00AM],[Jun  1 2014 12:00AM],[Jul  1 2014 12:00AM],[Aug  1 2014 12:00AM],[Sep  1 2014 12:00AM],[Oct  1 2014 12:00AM],[Nov  1 2014 12:00AM],[Dec  1 2014 12:00AM],[Jan  1 2015 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2015 12:00AM],[Mar  1 2015 12:00AM],[Apr  1 2015 12:00AM],[May  1 2015 12:00AM],[Jun  1 2015 12:00AM],[Jul  1 2015 12:00AM],[Aug  1 2015 12:00AM],[Sep  1 2015 12:00AM],[Oct  1 2015 12:00AM],[Nov  1 2015 12:00AM],[Dec  1 2015 12:00AM],[Jan  1 2016 12:00AM],[Feb  1 2016 12:00AM])) AS PVTTable
```

Comment: It successfully makes a new table with the correct Customer ID and dynamic month headings, but each Customer ID has several lines which all have the sum of subscription amount for different months

Comment: Let me ask a different way:  What do you get when you put `PRINT @DynamicPivotQuery` before the last line in your posted code?

Comment: I added it into the post - too long to comment

Comment: See the answer here, it looks like you need to specify `GROUP BY [Customer ID]`:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183160/sql-pivot-table-and-group-by-not-working

Comment: The pivot really should be doing the grouping already.... that was the point of pivoting in the first place. With this i'll have to sum all of the month columns which makes the dynamic part of the pivot obsolete too