# Dynamically convert column to rows and then join with other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that i like to combine together, the first are just an normal table. But the second the structure i having the problem with.[image]
I need to convert the rows in the column [Name] to columns. The two problem im having is that the picture only shows data from one id, and i need to convert distinct list of columns and then display the [value] column as rows. Second issue is to do all this while still joining the main table together with the table in the picture. I know that pivot exists and i have tried it. But can't get it to work, just with the main table.
Does anybody have an idea to have to solve this issue??
Here is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Name]) 
                    from [dbo].[TfsItem]
                    group by [Name]
                    order by [Name]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        SELECT @cols
set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select value, [Name]
                from [dbo].[TfsItem]
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for [Name] in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Thanks. I've edited that in as a tag to your question.

Comment: Try changing your pivot to use `max([Name])` instead of `max([value])`.

Comment: @S.C. I just tried it and it just converts it wrong and that sense that it just inserts a lot of null in the columns even if i know that it's not empty.

Comment: You are not selecting anything else, e.g. workitemid: select workitemid, value, [Name] from [dbo].[TfsItem]

Comment: @Ako, i have actually tried it but the performance are bad, so i actually dont get an result to verify, because im stopping it after 15 min

Comment: Maybe it helps not to select all the columns and all items, you can try by selecting top 10 rows.

Comment: You need to make sure that "ItemID" is in your final select. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15183160/6305294